# How to loop through the data I receive from snapshot.val() and push it to an array based on keys

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, ionic-framework, ionic3

I want to loop through the data I receive from `snapshot.val()` based on user keys and push them into an array. I tried doing it with the help of for..in loop like this,

```
firebase.database().ref('\interests').child("I would like to dine with").on('value', (snapshot) => {
  var data = snapshot.val();
  if(snapshot.exists()){
    for(let key in data){
      console.log("data[key]",data[key]);
      this.intVal.push(data[key]);
      console.log("intVal",this.intVal);
    }
  }
})
```

But I'm getting something like this,

[image]

If you notice, my first array contains 1 object under a user key and my second array contains 3 objects under their user keys. How can I push every single value in a separate array?

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks

Comment: every single value for a key in a new array , why would you want that ?

Comment: No, that is not what I meant sorry. If you see my console snapshot my intVal has 4 objects in it and each array has mutiple objects nested with its keys. Values from db is kind of repetitive here. I want to push every single object from db as an array under its random user key. So in my case, the result I'm expecting should have 4 arrays with one object as its child without any repetitive data. Sorry again for not being concise!

Comment: what intrigues me here is why are you getting random data . Can ot be handled in your fucntion? . This feels like a workaround

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There is a [`DataSnapshot.forEach()` method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#forEach) precisely for this purpose:

```
firebase.database().ref('\interests').child("I would like to dine with").on('value', (snapshot) => {
  snapshot.forEach((child) => {
    console.log(child.key, child.val()); 
    this.intVal.push(child.val());
    console.log("intVal",this.intVal);
  });
  }
})
```

Comment: Here all the properties and methods snapshot has: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot

Answer (score 5):

You can iterate over data again for each object

```
for(let key in data){
     console.log("data[key]",data[key]);
     for(innerKey in data[key]){
       var obj = {};
       obj[innerKey]=data[key][innerKey];
       this.intVal.push(obj);
     }
     console.log("intVal",this.intVal);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have not tested this code yet but should fit your need.

```
var interest = data.pop();//remove the interest
var uniq = data.reduce((unique, users) => {
    for (userId in users) {
        if (!userId in unique.IDs) {
            unique.IDs[userId] = users[userId];
            unique.usersList.push(users[userId]);
        }
    }
    return unique;
}, {IDs:{},usersList :[]});

console.log('interest is', interest);
console.log('uniq user ids', Object.keys(uniq.IDs));
console.log('uniq user list', uniq.usersList);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just using array map can solve all pain i think.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map