# Retrieving data on firebase having child key uid (javascript)

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native

I am struggling how to retrieve data from firebase having a child key, such as `uid`.

[image]

here is the structure of my firebase.

Currently I am making an admin panel which can read the order placed by each user and render it through flatlist in react native, but it seems that I can't access their order because every time the user places an order it is stored on their unique `User.id`

I don't know how to make a reference to the `User.id` child like `firebase.database().ref(orders/${AllUserId}/products)`

Comment: You want to retrieve id, image, price, title from your second uid?

Comment: the second one is the key generated by push() method, and yes I want to access it but the first one which is the uid of another user hinders me from accessing the second one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `forEach` loop to fetch ids and can get values as so

```
firebase.database().ref('order').on('value', (snapshot) => {

  snapshot.forEach((child) => {
      uid = child.key;  // gives uid1

      child.forEach((snap) =>{
          var id = snap.key; // first iteration gives uid2                          

          firebase.database().ref('order/'+uid+'/'+id).on('value', (snapchild) => {

                snapchild.forEach((snapshotchild) =>{
                  console.log(snapshotchild.val());                

                });
          });

      });
  });

});
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46146640/9493145) could be more insightful.

Comment: Thank you very much @Jagruti! I will try to integrate this one to my codes.